# How to suppress all warnings?

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to suppress all warnings and weak warnings for JavaScript in WebStorm by default?

(I already know how to suppress single warnings by pressing <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> and suppress Statement way)

Comment: 1) Configure your inspections -- disable unwanted ones? If you want to suppress them all ... then you do not need that inspection in first place. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html 2) Another idea -- Use Hector the Inspector guy icon in status bar and disable showing any warnings  for this file -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html

Comment: thank you I l was wondering what Hector is...